# How to Retrieve SD Card Files via fastboot or recovery?

Tags: usb, adb, clockworkmod-recovery, fastboot, mount

I have a Nexus 4 (LG E960) running rooted stock 4.2.2/JDQ39. The phone fell from a foot high and the screen cracked. The touchscreen no longer works.

I have a full Nandroid (TWRP type) backup under /storage/emulated/0/TWRP which I want to retrieve to install in the replacement phone.

I can connect via fastboot but I cannot connect via ADB (neither via Command-line OR Wug's Nexus Root Toolkit). ClockWorkMod v6.0.2.3 does not give the option to mount USB storage.

**I need to retrieve those files. I need to either connect via ADB (in recovery or use fastboot to enable ADB in booted up mode) OR mount USB storage. What are my options?**

PS: This [thread on XDA Dev](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2046252) does not help in my case as I do not want to erase my phone.

Comment: Do you have the USB drivers installed on your PC?  While the phone is in recovery mode and connected to your PC, what does the command `adb devices` return (in Windows Command Prompt)?

Comment: Yes, the USB drivers are in place, otherwise not even fastboot would connect. `adb devices` returns `no devices`.

Comment: Often fastboot drivers are different from the ones used by Recovery mode and/or fully-booted Android system.  I recommend re-installing the drivers.  You may need to delete existing drivers Windows decided to use.  Full instructions with driver download [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992345).

Comment: Are you able to boot normally, or into recovery? `adb` should work from either of those. Did you ever successfully connect with `adb` prior to the accident?

Comment: I did connect before fine, but only when booted and I turned on USB Debugging. Never connected ADB from recovery. I have the PDAnet drivers installed, and before I had the RAW drivers (I believe). USB Debugging was not left on, so trying to connect at the unlock screen does not work. An option would be to activate USB Debugging from fastboot, is that possible @Trebor ?

Comment: `Android Original ADB Interface` shows up in Device Manager when the phone is plugged in either Fastboot or Recovery. But no ADB in recovery. Is this normal?

Comment: Reinstalling the drivers for the 3rd time did it. I can now connect via ADB which allowed me to pull the files. Thanks @Chahk !

Comment: I'll post it as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often fastboot drivers are different from the ones used by Recovery mode and/or fully-booted Android system.  I would recommend re-installing the USB drivers on your PC.  You may need to delete existing drivers that Windows picked up. Full instructions with driver download for Nexus 4 [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1992345):

Quote:

> - Plug your phone into your computer.
> - Go to Device Manager on your computer and locate your device. It will either be under "Android Devices" or "Other Devices" depending
>     whether drivers have been installed or not.
> - Right click on your phone and select "Uninstall."
> - In the box that appears, check the option to "Delete the driver software for this device."
> - Go back to Device Manager and refresh.
> - Locate your phone and right click to select "Update Driver Software."
> - Manually install the drivers by picking the folder of the files you downloaded.
> - Unplug your phone and restart your computer.
> - Plug it back in and everything should work.
>
> Download link: http://www.mediafire.com/?8xb50uktar8096i

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, I know, but a viable alternative approach:

**Use a USB-OTG (On-the-Go) cable** to connect a mouse to your phone, so you can work around the non-functional touch screen. You may then be able to upload your data out of the phone, and perhaps even connect a USB hub to have both a mouse and a USB stick (and a keyboard?) accessible "locally" on the phone, in case uploading data is not an option for you.